# How to change the shortcut behavior of dock in multiple instances of window?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, launcher, dock

Here's my setup.
I have Firefox (can be any app really) pinned to my dock/launcher in 1st position.

And here's my scenario:

- Open two instances of Firefox (pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + 1 and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + 1)
- While still having one of the Firefox instance active, I press <kbd>Super</kbd> + 1 again (not knowing that I have that instance active)

Now in this scenario, my keyboard's focus is in the dock instead of the browser instance (maybe dock is asking me to pick the right instance?).
Anyway, this is annoying because in my mind, I've switched to the Firefox instance already and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+T to open a new tab it wouldn't work because the keyboard's focus is still in the dock.

So, the main question really is, how do I get the dock to select the first instance (or any instance of app) when pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + `<n>` and not have my keyboard's focus in dock?

Comment: FYI, I know I can press Enter to focus the window if there are multiple instances of window but it's inconsistent with single instance window and I always have to backtrack and press Enter after pressing shortcut keys of the window that I'm interested in.

Comment: In 22.04, pressing super+1 again shows miniatures of the windows in order to select, so there is a clear visual clue which may not be there in 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the behavior to cycle windows instead by changing the setting `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock` `click-action` to `'cycle-windows'`, using `dconf-editor` or with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
```

Be aware that that also will change the behavior when you click on the icon in the dash instead of using the shortcut key.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I used `skip` instead of `cycle-windows` to avoid cycling through the windows. I don't mind change in the click behavior as I mostly use keyboard shortcuts to navigate windows. Thank you very much for taking me to right direction.